# Select Top 3 from joined tables, apply rank based on column value

Tags: google-bigquery

Table1

```
ID         | JoinedStart        | CohortID | CohortName
---------- | ------------------ | -------- | ----------
1          | 20080101 01:30:00  | 1        | Peanut
1          | 20090204 01:01:00  | 2        | Apple
2          | 20190107 05:52:14  | 1        | Peanut
3          | 20190311 02:35:26  | 2        | Apple
6          | 20190311 02:35:26  | 2        | Apple
```

Table 2

```
ID         | event_start   | StartDateTimestamp2
---------- | ------------- | -------------------
1          | HiredStart    | 20080501 01:30:00
1          | DeferredStart | 20090604 01:01:00
2          | HiredStart    | 20190115 05:52:14
3          | HiredStart    | 20190330 02:35:26
6          | DeferredStart | 20190330 02:35:26
```

Attempt 1

```
SELECT CohortID, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CohortID ASC) RANK, t1.id, event_start, startdatetimestamp2
FROM table1 e JOIN table 2 ON table2.id = table1.id
```

Then I tried:

```
SELECT CohortID, (CASE WHEN CohortID = 1 THEN RANK() OVER(ORDER BY(StartDateTimestamp2) ASC)
                       WHEN CohortID = 2 THEN RANK() OVER(ORDER BY(StartDateTimestamp2) ASC) END)
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.user_id = table2.user_id
```

Expected Output

```
CohortID   | RANK | ID | CohortName | startdatetimestamp2     
---------- | -----|----|------------|-------------------
1          | 1    | 1  | Peanut     | 20080501 01:30:00
1          | 2    | 2  | Peanut     | 20090604 01:01:00
1          | 3    | 6  | Apple      | 20190115 05:52:14
2          | 1    | 3  | Apple      | 20190330 02:35:26
2          | 2    | 5  | Peanut     | 20190115 05:52:14
```

The Rank restarts when the CohortId changes from 1 to 2, from 123 to 12.

My above query just ranks in a weird sequence. How do I make it so that it restarts every time top 3 when the CohortID is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a query which generates a rank assignment, per cohort, and then subquery and retain only ranks of 3 or less:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.CohortID, t1.ID, t1.CohortName, t2.startdatetimestamp2,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.CohortID ORDER BY t2.StartDateTimestamp2) rnk
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
)

SELECT CohortID, rnk AS "RANK", ID, CohortName, startdatetimestamp2    
FROM cte
WHERE "RANK" <= 3
ORDER BY CohortID, "RANK";
```